# What is the difference between dexp and pexp

Tags: probability, distributions

I understand probability distribution but I am having a hard time getting a grasp on probability density function, specifically difference between dexp (density of exponential distribution) and pexp (probability distribution of exponential distribution)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What do you intend by "probability distribution"? Are you referring to the [cdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), or something else?

Comment: Glen, are cdf and simply density function both the same ?

Comment: No, they're different. The density is the derivative of the cdf, the cdf is the integral of the density. The cdf is $P(X\leq x)$.

Comment: Thanks Glen I think I am little more closer to my understanding now, I used this example for exponential distribution where λ=4 and x=0.5 in the case of pdf exp(λ=4,x=0.5) is 0.89 for density function exp(λ=4,x=0.5) is 0.54....

Comment: wait, no, you're confused -- "*pdf*" is exactly the same thing as "density function"

Comment: Okay lets go back to the example i mentioned earlier exponential distribution exp(λ=4,x=0.5) how will you frame a question addressing a density function, how will you frame a question addressing a distribution function ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking there. If I am framing a question asking about the density, I'll ask about "the density", or "the pdf". If I am asking a question about the distribution function, I'll ask about "the distribution function" or "the cdf", so I'd frame a question in those terms. Could you clarify what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose X is an exponential random variable. 
pexp(c) is the probability that X is less than or equal to c. pexp is always non-decreasing. To prove this, let m>0, then pexp(c+m)=P(X

dexp(c) is the derivative of pexp(c), but intuitively, it is the probability that X is 'near' c, or the 'density' of the probability mass. The chance X lands on exactly each number is zero, but when we sum over the infinite real numbers in any interval, we get a finite probability that X falls in that interval. This is decreasing, since an exponential random variable is more likely to be between 1 and 2 than between 100 and 101.

A CDF is NOT a density function. A density is a mass divided by a length. A CDF doesn't define the length where the probability mass is, just that it is left of c.

Comment: Let me start from here, density is the derivative of distribution and CDF is the integral of the distribution is that correct ?